# facebook Registration Plugin password field length must be 8 characters

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to use facebook Registration Plugin in my site.. and i dont want to have any rules on the password field.. the problem I have is if someone type password less than 8 characters and click register button.
the plugin not redirecting to the redirect_uri and dosent show any error at all.. in my console i can see that https://www.facebook.com/ajax/connect/registration_widget.php return code 500 and its say "Sorry, something went wrong."
if i change the password field to be atleast 8 characters and click the register button again its working fine..
this is my code:

```
<fb:registration redirect_uri="http://example.com" class=span12 fields='[
 {"name":"name"},
 {"name":"email"},
 {"name":"location"},
 {"name":"gender"},
 {"name":"birthday"},
 {"name":"password"},
]'/>
```

i have no javascript validation or something like that all I want is that users will be able to type short password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears to be a bug:
they working on fixing it right now i hope so
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/713074325400184/